# Tipa change font style doesn't work

Tags: fonts, linguistics, tipa

I tried changing the tipa font style, but it only works for the typewriter style... I used the same examples as the manual, but bold, sans serif and slanted don't change...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\usepackage[T1]{tipa}
\usepackage{tipx}

\begin{document}


Slanted
\textipa{\slshape f@"nEtIks}
\textipa{\textsl{f@"nEtIks}}
\textsl{\textipa{f@"nEtIks}}

Bold
\textipa{\bfseries f@"nEtIks}
\textipa{\textbf{f@"nEtIks}}
\textbf{\textipa{f@"nEtIks}}

Sans serif
\textipa{\sffamily f@"nEtIks}
\textipa{\textsf{f@"nEtIks}}
\textsf{\textipa{f@"nEtIks}}

Type writer
\textipa{\ttfamily f@"nEtIks}
\textipa{\texttt{f@"nEtIks}}
\texttt{\textipa{f@"nEtIks}}


\end{document}
```

It should look like this, that's the example from the manual

[image: example from the manual]

That is my example...

[image: my work example]

Comment: There is no support for the T3 encoding in ClearSans, so the substitution font (the TIPA default) enters.

Comment: @egreg ok ... and why does the substitution font changes to typewriter, but not to bold, slanted, or sans serif? It doesn't bothers me if it is another font for the tipa characters...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no support for the T3 encoding in the ClearSans family. Indeed, you get three warnings from your input file:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T3/ClearSans-LF/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T3/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 11.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T3/ClearSans-LF/m/sl' undefined
(Font)              using `T3/ClearSans-LF/m/n' instead on input line 11.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T3/ClearSans-LF/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T3/ClearSans-LF/m/n' instead on input line 16.
```

The first warning says that ClearSans-LF has no T3 encoded font available, so `cmr` is substituted. The second substitutes to the slanted font the only one available, again `cmr` and so for the last one.

Since the `ClearSans` package does nothing to the monospaced font, you get the normal one.

If you want to have *good* substitutions, you have to define them.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}

\usepackage[T1]{tipa}
\usepackage{tipx}

\DeclareFontFamily{T3}{ClearSans-LF}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T3}{ClearSans-LF}{m}{n}
 {<-> ssub * cmss/m/n }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T3}{ClearSans-LF}{b}{n}
 {<-> ssub * cmss/bx/n }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T3}{ClearSans-LF}{m}{it}
 {<-> ssub * cmss/m/sl }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T3}{ClearSans-LF}{m}{sl}
 {<-> ssub * cmss/m/sl }{}

\begin{document}

Slanted
\textipa{\slshape f@"nEtIks}
\textipa{\textsl{f@"nEtIks}}
\textsl{\textipa{f@"nEtIks}}

Bold
\textipa{\bfseries f@"nEtIks}
\textipa{\textbf{f@"nEtIks}}
\textbf{\textipa{f@"nEtIks}}

Sans serif
\textipa{\sffamily f@"nEtIks}
\textipa{\textsf{f@"nEtIks}}
\textsf{\textipa{f@"nEtIks}}

Type writer
\textipa{\ttfamily f@"nEtIks}
\textipa{\texttt{f@"nEtIks}}
\texttt{\textipa{f@"nEtIks}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you :) If i want to use only the bold version in a document i think it's enough to use \declare font family.... and then \declare font shape... for the bold version... Just to understand better i think the second \declare font is for bold and the last one for slanted... But for which font shape are the first and third one?

Comment: @Katharina `{m}{n}` is the “normal font”, `{b}{n}` the bold one and so on.

Comment: thanks i really appreciate your help... For which font shape is `\DeclareFontShape{T3}{ClearSans-LF}{m}{it}
 {<-> ssub * cmss/m/sl }{}` ... It doesn't seem to change anything if I delete it..

Comment: @Katharina Just in case you use `\textit`

Answer (score 3):

old question but I have found a much better solution.

```
\usepackage{substitutefont}
\substitutefont{T3}{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\substitutefont{T3}{\sfdefault}{phv}
\substitutefont{T3}{\ttdefault}{cmtt}
```

What this does - it tells the LaTeX compiler that when it encounters the respective defaults in the T3 encoding, instead of using the font specified as the default, use the replacement (e.g. ptm which is Times instead of whatever the serif default is). Then LaTeX will look for the t3 encoding file for that replacement, which is present in the tipa package directory, and use it (`t3ptm.fd`,`t3phv.fd`,`t3cmtt.fd`) so the tipa fonts get used.