# Can't use bold IPA symbols {lmodern}

Tags: fonts, linguistics, tipa

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313174/tipa-change-font-style-doesnt-work?newreg=23071af860f0440f9c36d6e8c90d10e2) thread solves the problem I have, although I can't quite get it to work with `lmodern` fonts.

```
\documentclass[titlepage, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{tipa}

\begin{document}
\textipa{Z}
\textbf{[\textbeta]}
\end{document}
```

It should produce a normal symbol and a bold symbol but it prints the normal ones and I get this warnings

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T3/lmr/m/n' undefined
(Font) using `T3/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T3/lmr/bx/n' undefined
(Font) using `T3/lmr/m/n' instead
(Font) for symbol `textbeta' on input line 9.
```

I didn't really understand the matter so I'm not sure how to readapt the answer to my case, and I can't comment as I'm a new user. This is what I tried

```
\DeclareFontFamily{T3}{lmr}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T3}{lmr}{m}{n}
 {<-> ssub * cmr/m/n }{}
\DeclareFontShape{T3}{lmr}{bx}{n}
 {<-> ssub * cmr/m/n }{}
```

but the result is

```
! LaTeX Error: Encoding scheme `T3' unknown.
...
! LaTeX Error: Font family `T3+lmr' unknown.
...
! LaTeX Error: Font family `T3+lmr' unknown.
...
```

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get two warnings:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T3/lmr/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T3/cmr/m/n' instead
(Font)              for symbol `textbeta' on input line 13.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T3/lmr/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T3/cmr/m/n' instead
(Font)              for symbol `textbeta' on input line 13.
```

The first one is the most important and tells you that Latin Modern fonts don't support IPA, so the default substitution is made. However, this substitution is not able to guess other weights, so you get the medium series font in all cases.

You can use `\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution`:

```
\documentclass[titlepage, oneside]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{tipa}


\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{T3}{lmr}{cmr}

\begin{document}
\textbf{[\textbeta]} [\textbeta]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: see edit history for a previous solution using the `substitutefont` package, now declared obsolete.

Comment: Thank you! I changed the post a little but the answer is still on point. Sorry for the mess, first post :)