# Bolding IPA symbols with tipa

Tags: xetex, unicode, bold, linguistics, tipa

I am using the `tipa` package for IPA in my dissertation. I would like to bold certain symbols, and have tried, e.g.: `\textbf{\textipa{\!d}}`. However, they do not bold in Latex's default font (computer modern). I cannot switch to `tipauni` without having to redo several days worth of IPA transcription (e.g., many characters that I used like `\textprimstress` do not seem to work in tipauni) and switching fonts would affect the spacing in tables. Is there a way to use unicode only for a couple particular IPA symbols (U+0257 ɗ and U+0261 ɡ), so that they can be bolded, but keep using the `tipa` package for the rest? e.g. [`\textbf{ɡ}\textipa{@}\textprimstress \textbf{ɗ}a`] where `ɡ` and `ɗ` are defined as unicode or something that is able to be bolded in computer modern font?

```
\documentclass[
  normalmargins,
  10pt,
  openany,
  onehalfspacing,
]{article}

\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
[\textbf{\textscriptg}\textipa{@}\textprimstress \textbf{\textipa{\!d}}a] 
[\textbf{ɡ}\textipa{@}\textprimstress \textbf{ɗ}a] 
\end{document}
```

Comment: You've tagged this `xetex` are you compiling with `xelatex` or `pdflatex`? Could you edit your question to include a small compilable document that shows what you're doing.

Comment: I used xelatex.

Comment: So you're also loading `fontspec`?

Comment: Yes, I also have fontspec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend going to a font that supports IPA. Anyway, you can solve the problems in the question also with `tipa`.

First you have to tell LaTeX to substitute `cmr` for `lmr` when T3 encoding is used (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/458064/4427), but you need something else in order to directly use Unicode characters.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{T3}{lmr}{cmr}
\newunicodechar{ɡ}{\textscriptg}
\newunicodechar{ɗ}{\textipa{\!d}}

\begin{document}

[\textbf{\textscriptg}\textipa{@}\textprimstress \textbf{\textipa{\!d}}a]

[\textbf{ɡ}\textipa{@}\textprimstress \textbf{ɗ}a]

\end{document}
```

[image]